# How to validate my form using javascript in docpad

Tags: javascript, html, docpad

I am trying to use a simple docpad skeleton to set up a form that in turn is validated. I guess this is me not using docpad correctly, as the validation javascript and forms-html is copied from [bootstrapValidator](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator).

[html-file in my out folder](http://pastebin.com/JRU3QfkR)

```
val.js: pastebin.com/kfg3CKKj

default.html.jade: pastebin.com/kWVAtBEz
```

When i click the "submit"-button on my form it seems that the page is refreshing, without validation. I've also tried with `jquery.validate`. Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my jquery-selector was wrong.

```
 $('defaultForm').bootstrapValidator({
```

should be

```
 $('#defaultForm')').bootstrapValidator({
```